# Prevent mysql query to be executed more than once

Tags: mysql

Background: our application saves data to MySQL by sending requests through a message queue(RabbitMQ in our case) to a group of consumers. The consumers will connect to MySQL then execute the requests.

If a consumer crashed, then other consumers will pick up the un-acked request and dot it again.

But network problems also may cause the request is not acked then trigger other consumers to process the request more than once.

The business logic is complex so we cannot make the MySQL query idempotent. So we need a way to prevent the query to be executed more than once.

We have a naive idea. Basic we generate a UUID for every query. Before we execute the query we need to insert the UUID into a table in which the UUID is a primary key. If the insert is failed, the query won't be executed.

We don't have a lot of background on MySQL, so the question is: Is this the best to prevent a query to be executed more than once in MySQL? Is there any serious flaw behind this method?

Thanks.

Comment: Your selection of RabbitMQ indicates you want extreme performance, instead of serial processing. Extreme performance **requires** idempotency. If you cannot achieve idempotency, then I would suggest you switch to transactional queues, such as ActiveMQ that do not require idempotency. This is a whole paradigm change, though. Do you really need extreme performance, or just fast performance will do?

Comment: Even if the MQ can archive exactly-once itself, If the consumer sends the query to MySQL then crashed before responding to MQ, there still are chances a query will be executed more than once?

Comment: If the query is executed in a transactional manner, then a crash won't have any lasting impact on the data.

Comment: Yes. What I worried about is that MySQL successfully executed the query. But the consumer failed to report to the message queue that this query is handled successfully(Due to the consumer crash). Then another consumer may pick up the request again and execute it again.

Comment: If the queues are transactional (e.g. ActiveMQ) then database changes and queue reading/writing will all be part of the same single two-phase-commit transaction. However, it seems you don't want transactional queues, but prefer RabbitMQ instead, that does not offer this feature.

Comment: If you need to use RabbitMQ (so you can't have transactional queues) then I would recommend you use the "Transactional Outbox" pattern. See: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your advice. I'm not familiar with ActiveMQ. After some search, it seems ActiveMQ suggested an alternative way which is similar to what we think about. https://activemq.apache.org/should-i-use-xa